# How to actually initiate a function from another file in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have this in a file called, say, User.jsx

```
   shrink() {
        this.setState({shrunk: !this.state.shrunk});
        let stuff = document.querySelectorAll(".stuff");
        for (let i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
            stuff[i].classList.toggle("do-something");
        }
    }
```

And I'm importing into another file (called "Person.jsx") like so:

```
import { shrink } from './User.jsx';
```

And I'm trying to use it within the Person.jsx file like so:

```
class Stuff extends React.Component {
    doStuff() {
      shrink(); **/* How do I actually initiate the function? */**
    }
    return (
        <div onClick={this.doStuff}>Yo!</div>
    )

}
```

My question is how to I actually initiate that function so it works properly.

I've also tried to "return" it as well:

```
return shrink();
```

but says "shrink" is undefined....

Comment: You should check out https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app You're missing some pieces here I think. Otherwise you'd need to export it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: That's not really how you should make React components interact. If the User is a parent of the Person component then you can pass the fx down to Person as a property. If they aren't directly related and the fx will change the state in some way then you need to make it an redux action. If you just want the fx purely for its functionality, then you either need to re-define it in Person or just have a extra utility file (that can be plain JS) which you can import in both User and Person and call that file's fxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export it

```
export function shrink() {
    this.setState({shrunk: !this.state.shrunk});
    let stuff = document.querySelectorAll(".stuff");
    for (let i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
        stuff[i].classList.toggle("do-something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @hana-alaydrus and how would I actually use it in the other file? Just like I have above? Something different? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelSebastian sorry for late reply, yes just like the way you import it above